# How can I Monitor one folder in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, windows-services

I am creating application like Google Drive.

I want to monitor one folder in client PC.If client made any changes in that folder like , Create a new folder ,Create File,move file or directory,copy directory or file etc.

If any change made on PC that would be go online server .and If any changes done on Online server that would be reflect offline.

I am confused how to achieve this.

I am planning to create WIN SERVICE for folder monitoring and if any changes done then it calls wcf service which will exactly create same folder on online server and upload a file.

One more idea is: In winservice I maintain XML of Directory structure.When service start it again create xml of directory structure and compare old and new xml , if there has been any changes then it will call wcf. but this would not be suitable as per my thinking.

Please give me suggestions to achieve this task.
Consider This Scenario.

In Client Machine 
C:\Myfiles
If any folder created in Myfiles like A,B or any subfolder created in A->A1

Then I should be informed this folder created and that would be created in WEB Application.

Similarly same structure created on online server.
If any changes made online like Created subfolder in A->A2
Then same folder should be created in client machine.

Comment: You need to do more research. It seems unclear what your current question is. Describe some scenarios (1. Folder contains files X and Y, 2. Service restarts. 3. Service now finds files X and Z) and decide whether your approach can handle such scenarios. For detecting filesystem activity at runtime, see FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: I have added description

Comment: Now it's still too broad. You're basically asking _"Please explain how I can write a DropBox client-server architecture"_, which is too broad. Do some research and ask a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class in System.IO, should help your requirement.
You can subscribe to the events to know about the file/directory changes and then sync it to the other machine by some communication channel like webservice.

This [link](http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/how-build-folder-watcher-service-c) has a detailed explanation on the FileSystemWatcher implementation.